# Parsing an XML file within a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

**Note:**

I posted this question back when I only had a master node in my Jenkins environment. This made serialization a lesser issue as there were no other nodes to communicate with, thus the code here will not run as expected on a multi-node environment (for instance, `readFile` will only read files from the master node).

In my experience it's better to have your configuration written in other formats (JSON, YAML, Groovy which are all supported natively in Jenkins), or use external tools (such as `xmllint` on Linux) if you don't have control over the file's format.

**Original question:**

I have an XML file which I'd like to use as input for a pipeline script. Problem is the XMLParser isn't serializable so I put it in a NonCPS function, but I lost the Node object because of that.

This is the pipeline script:

```java
def buildPlanPath = 'C:\\buildPlan_test.xml'

@NonCPS
groovy.util.Node getBuildPlan(path) {
    new XmlParser().parseText(readFile(path))
}
    
node {
    //def buildPlan = new XmlParser().parseText(readFile(buildPlanPath))
    groovy.util.Node buildPlan = getBuildPlan(buildPlanPath)

    println buildPlan.getClass()
    println buildPlan
    println buildPlan.branch
}
```

This is an input sample:

```xml
<branch name='mybranch'>
    <stage>
        <job name='job11' />
        <job name='job12' />
    </stage>
    <stage>
        <job name='job21' />
        <job name='job22' />
        <job name='job23' />
    </stage>
    <stage>
        <job name='job31' />
    </stage>
</branch>
```

This is the result:

```
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in C:\Jenkins\workspace\pipeline-develop
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
class java.lang.String
[Pipeline] echo
<branch name='mybranch'>
  <stage>
    <job name='job11' />
    <job name='job12' />
  </stage>
  <stage>
    <job name='job21' />
    <job name='job22' />
    <job name='job23' />
  </stage>
  <stage>
    <job name='job31' />
  </stage>
</branch>
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: branch for class: java.lang.String
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:25)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:16)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:62)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor327.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:183)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm using Jenkins 2.7 with pipeline 2.1, which are currently the latest.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to format the configuration in groovy rather than in XML and load it just like any other code piece...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I think my approach was wrong: I decided to convert the XML file into a separate groovy script and load it within the pipeline

**Update**: Recently people started editing my answer for clarity, but the fact is that I just ditched storing my configuration in XML files and opted for groovy scripts, which gave me more flexibility. I understand it may not be a common practice, but it suits my needs.

For example - instead of:

```
config.xml:
<settings>
  <floopi>2</floopi>
</settings>
```

I used:

```
config.groovy:
[
  floopi: 2
]
```

And in the pipeline script:

```
stage('init') {
    def settings = load('config.groovy')
    echo "floopi: ${settings.floopi}"
}
```

I hope that's a better answer :)

Comment: You can simplify the "config.groovy" like this: `[ floopi: 2 ]`. There is no need for the `call()` function and `return this`. Omitting these makes the groovy script look like a pure configuration file.

Comment: Simplified answer. Thanks @zett42, only 1 year late :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use XmlSlurper, it works for me.

```
def xmlText = new XmlSlurper().parse(MyURL)
xmlText.data.artifact.each {******
```

Comment: Woudn't you need to import the XmlSlurper?

Comment: This is not a best practicE!!!
This will run as a lightweight task on the master.

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify what the data pulled from MyURL looks like to have a better idea how to process the data

Answer (score 0):

As branch is the root element, you don't need to explicitly specify it when accessing your parsed nodes

Try changing

```
println buildPlan.branch
```

To

```
println buildPlan.stage
```

To print out the stage nodes

Comment: I tried the change but still got the `MissingPropertyException`. Actually my problem is with serialization - I haven't figured out yet how do I keep the `groovy.util.Node` object from `new XmlParser().parseText(readFile(path))` without turning it into a string

Comment: what do you mean by _"keep"_?

Comment: I meant I wanted the Node object itself to be returned (thus the declaration at the function), but instead I lost it and got its string representation as a return value

Answer (score 0):

A `@NonCPS` method should only accept or return `Serializable` types. Try returning `.branch` from the method.

Comment: Unfortunately anything after `new XmlParser().parseText(readFile(path))` seems to be ignored...I could type anything I wanted and still got the whole file contents as a string (I tried `.branch`, `.branch[0]`, `branch[0].stage[1]`... even `.nonExistentTag`)

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend a [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).  That will allow you to

- centralize logic
- write unit tests - via [jenkins pipeline unit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) and perhaps Spock
- use this kind of approach

### Src dir

```
class PipelineSupport {
    PipelineSupport(def env, def jenkinsStepAccess) {
        this.env = env
        this.jenkinsStepAccess = jenkinsStepAccess

    }
    def readXml(def path) {
        def text = jenkinsStepAccess.readFile(path)
        def parser = new XmlParser()
        def xml = parser.parseText(text.toString())
        return xml
    }
}
```

### vars dir  var/foo.groovy

```
import ...PipelineSupport

Map readXml(def path) {
    // pass env and "this" access point to jenkins DSL to calls
    return new PipelineSupport(env, this).readXml(path)
}
```

### use in a build

```
library "mylib"
def xmlData = foo.readXml('path/to/bar.xml')
```

Comment: Having shared libraries is always good practice regardless of the issue we're facing. While it may be a too general solution, it might be relevant here because the master node runs the shared library's code, so if we do all the XML processing within the shared library it could work. However, this is an old issue and the `XmlParser` is considered deprecated, and also `readXml` returns a `Node`, not a `Map`.

Comment: When I originally posted this question I only had one node (shame on me), so using non-serializable methods was less of an issue. `readFile` should not be used when there are more 2 or more nodes, as it will always try to read from the master node. I'll update my question.