# Parsing pom.xml file within a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to parse my pom.xml in jenkins pipeline plugin. I intend to modify it and save it back.

My problem is that it gives me "unclassified field java.lang.String version"

My code is as follows:

```
@NonCPS
groovy.util.Node getPom(path) {
  new XmlParser().parseText(readFile(path)).version
}
node {
  groovy.util.Node pomNode = getPom("pom.xml")
  println pomNode
}
```

Similar issue has been discussed here: [Parsing an XML file within a Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643447/parsing-an-xml-file-within-a-jenkins-pipeline)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use (you need pipeline utility steps plugin for this):

```
pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
```

Now you have access to all data in the pom (as a [`Model`](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Model.html)).

Comment: A perfect answer. Correct and extremely quick.
Just a quick question, how would I save the pom file back after modifying it (I used setVersion() to set the version of the pom)?

Comment: You can use `writeMavenPom` (see https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/ for reference)

Comment: Another very quick one, I tried to save, and it does save the file but in the parent directory. Then I researched a bit and found that there is an optional parameter "file" that can be given with the desired path to the file. But I have filed to figure out how to feed that file parameter to my writeMavenPom. Could not find any example command anywhere.
Thanks again!

Comment: *failed to figure out